# Using leaflet in native web component

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-component

I'm trying to use leaflet inside of a web component. Here's my code.

I've copy pasted the standard example on leaflet website, but given it a HTMLElement rather than id string.

```js
class InfoWithMap extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    let container = `
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <div id='container'>
      <div>Name: Someone</div>
      <div>Location: Some place</div>
      <div id='map'></div>
    </div>`
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = container;
    
    let mapDiv = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('map');
    var map = L.map(mapDiv).setView([51.505, -0.09], 19);

    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('info-with-map', InfoWithMap);


let m = document.createElement('info-with-map');
document.getElementById('main').append(m);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="main"> 
</div>
```

However, as you can see the map is not being shown properly.

Any idea what is wrong with the setup?

**Edit:** It may not be easy to see the problem in the limited space of inline output here. Hence, here are the codepens to compare outputs of Leaflet with and without web components.

- [Without web components](https://codepen.io/mrbrahman/pen/GRGwKqL)
- [With web components](https://codepen.io/mrbrahman/pen/mdjavmy)

Notice in the output of web component, the tiles are not displayed properly.

Comment: A map is shown; please explain _not being shown properly_

Comment: The tiles are not displayed properly. I've updated the description to provide a comparison of outputs with and without web components. Notice the one without web components prints multiple tiles, but the one using web components does not print all titles properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the Leaflet CSS to the global scope; but global CSS can not style shadowDOM

You need to load that CSS **inside** the shadowDOM because it arranges all the async loaded IMG tiles **inside** shadowDOM.

You also **do not** want to load the `<script src=".../leaflet.js">` in your HTML.
It is a dependency of the Web Component. So the (JSWC) Web Component loads it *when required*

```html
<style>
  maps { display:grid; grid:90px 90px/1fr 1fr; gap:5px; background:green }
</style>
<maps>
  <leaflet-map coords="52.09,5.12"></leaflet-map><leaflet-map coords="52.372,4.885"></leaflet-map>
  <leaflet-map coords="51.924,4.47"></leaflet-map><leaflet-map coords="50.85,5.69"></leaflet-map>
</maps>
<script>
  customElements.define('leaflet-map', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = 
        `<style>.leaflet-control-zoom{display:none}</style>` + 
        `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.skypack.dev/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css">` +
        `<div style="height:100%"/>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      if (window.L) this.render(); // if Leaflet already loaded as global Object
      else document.head.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("script"),{
                         src : "//unpkg.com/leaflet@latest/dist/leaflet.js", 
                         onload : () => this.render() }))
    }
    render(){
      this.map = L.map(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div'));
      this.map.addLayer(L.tileLayer("//tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { }));
      this.setView( ...this.getAttribute("coords").split(",") );
    }
    setView( lat, lon, zoom=this.getAttribute("zoom")||13 ){
        this.map.setView([lat, lon], zoom);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So silly of me! Didn't realize about the CSS scopes inside web component..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I learned so much more than just getting Leaflet to work with web components :-)