Leaflet.js as Web Component - Impossible to Display Map Properly because Shadow Dom
This simple Leaflet example works perfectly with vanilla JavaScript but does not when using Web Components (tiles show up all messed up https://imgur.com/a/ZicDrRQ).
My best guess is the way the Shadow DOM behaves with the #map element sizing, oddly enough if we change #map to display: flex slightly more tiles show up but still many are missing.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet.js with OpenStreetMap and Geolocation as Web Component</title>

    <!-- Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />

    <!-- Leaflet JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<style>
    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <geo-map></geo-map>

    <script>
        class GeoMap extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

                this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
                    <style>
                        :host {
                            display: inline-block;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                        }

                        #map {
                            display: inline-block;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <div id="map"></div>
                `;
            }

            connectedCallback() {
                const mapDiv = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#map');
                const map = L.map(mapDiv);
                L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                }).addTo(map);
                map.setView([34.42696537699258, -119.7175455093384], 13);
            }
        }

        customElements.define('geo-map', GeoMap);
    </script>

</body>

</html>


If you use shadow dom, should not you attach the Leaflet CSS inside as well?

Why do you need shadowDOM? With most 3rd party libraries that where never built to work with shadowDOM its like trying to force a square peg in a round hole. And did you search prior to asking? Marking it as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331601/using-leaflet-in-native-web-component/75339272#75339272

@ghybs you are right! that was the issue. Thank you!
